# Is there any way to stop a Stream.generate from its Lambda closure?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I just started playing around Java 8 and Lambda Expression and I am curious if I can stop the Stream generation from inside the Lambda expession by returning a specific value
(like null). Is this possible with Stream.generate()?

```
private int counter;

private void generate()
{
    System.out.println(Stream.generate(() -> {
        if (counter < 10) {
            counter++;
            return RandomUtils.nextInt(100);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }).count());
}
```

Unfortunately this code does not terminate, so by simply returning `null` will not step out of the stream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible with Lamdas, you cannot control the flow from inside the expression.
Even the API docs says that the Stream.generate generates an infinite stream.

However, you can limit the Stream and achieve the desired functionality simply by using the limit() method:

```
System.out.println(Stream.generate(() -> RandomUtils.nextInt(100)).limit(10).count());
```

Comment: This is not true.

Answer (score 42):

Java 9 and later includes [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
Stream<T> takeWhile(Predicate<? super T> predicate);
```

to limit a stream by condition. So the workaround beneath is not needed anymore.

**Original answer (for Java versions earlier than 9):**

With **Stream.generate** this is per definition **not** possible from a lambda closure. It is by definition endless. Using `limit()` you are able make your stream fix sized. But this will not help you for conditions like:

```
if random>10 then stop
```

There is a possibility to limit a potential endless stream by condition. This is usefull if one does not know the size. Your friend here is a **Spliterator** and your sample code would look like:

```
System.out.println( StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(new Iterator<Integer>() {
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return counter < 10;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        counter++;
        return RandomUtils.nextInt(100);
    }
}, Spliterator.IMMUTABLE), false).count());
```

Basically you are able to build a **Stream** from an **Iterator**. I am using this construct e.g. for a stream of **XMLEvents** from Stax XML - parsing.

I know this is not done by lambda constructs but it IHMO solves this lacking feature of stopping the stream item generation by condition.

I would be very interested, if there is a better way to achieve this (I mean this stream construct and not the XML processing ;)) or if there is a fundamental flaw in using streams in this way.

Comment: Sometimes it's not possible to know if there is a next element, which makes both solutions impossible.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Imagine a stream that flattens a set of sets returned in futures. You want to start streaming before all the sets are available, so you don't know if there are more elements contained in the future sets.

Answer (score 1):

```
// If you are not looking for parallelism, you can use following method:
public static <T> Stream<T> breakStream(Stream<T> stream, Predicate<T> terminate) { 
  final Iterator<T> original = stream.iterator();
  Iterable<T> iter = () -> new Iterator<T>() { 
    T t;
    boolean hasValue = false;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() { 
      if (!original.hasNext()) { 
        return false;
      } 
      t = original.next();
      hasValue = true;
      if (terminate.test(t)) { 
        return false;
      } 
      return true;
    } 

    @Override
    public T next() { 
      if (hasValue) { 
        hasValue = false;
        return t;
      } 
      return t;
    } 
  };

  return StreamSupport.stream(iter.spliterator(), false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [StreamSupport.stream(Spliterator, boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-)
See JavaDoc on [Spliterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html).
Here is example spliterator:

```
public class GeneratingSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T>
{
    private Supplier<T> supplier;
    private Predicate<T> predicate;

    public GeneratingSpliterator(final Supplier<T> newSupplier, final Predicate<T> newPredicate)
    {
        supplier = newSupplier;
        predicate = newPredicate;
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize()
    {
        return Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(final Consumer<? super T> action)
    {
        T newObject = supplier.get();
        boolean ret = predicate.test(newObject);
        if(ret) action.accept(newObject);
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution for java 8 (It needs a Stream.Builder, may be it is not optimal, but it is quite simple):

```
@SuppressWarnings("ResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
public static <T> Stream<T> streamBreakable(Stream<T> stream, Predicate<T> stopCondition) {
    Stream.Builder<T> builder = Stream.builder();
    stream.map(t -> {
                boolean stop = stopCondition.test(t);
                if (!stop) {
                    builder.add(t);
                }
                return stop;
            })
            .filter(result -> result)
            .findFirst();

    return builder.build();
}
```

And the test:

```
@Test
public void shouldStop() {

    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.generate(() -> {
        if (count.getAndIncrement() < 10) {
            return (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });

    List<Integer> list = streamBreakable(stream, Objects::isNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It *is* possible, you just need to think outside the box.

The following idea is borrowed from Python, the language which introduced me to generator functions...

Just throw an instance of `RuntimeException` when you are done from within the `Supplier<T>` closure and catch-and-ignore it at the call site.

An example excerpt (note I have added a safety catch of `Stream.limit(Long.MAX_VALUE)` to cover the unexpected, though it should never be triggered):

```
static <T> Stream<T> read(String path, FieldSetMapper<T> fieldSetMapper) throws IOException {
    ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(path);
    DefaultLineMapper<T> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(getTokenizer(resource));

    return Stream.generate(new Supplier<T>() {
        FlatFileItemReader<T> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        int line = 1;
        {
            itemReader.setResource(resource);
            itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
            itemReader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy());
            itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
            itemReader.open(new ExecutionContext());
        }

        @Override
        public T get() {
            T item = null;
            ++line;
            try {
                item = itemReader.read();
                if (item == null) {
                    throw new StopIterationException();
                }
            } catch (StopIterationException ex) {
                throw ex;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOG.log(WARNING, ex,
                        () -> format("%s reading line %d of %s", ex.getClass().getSimpleName(), line, resource));
            }
            return item;
        }
    }).limit(Long.MAX_VALUE).filter(Objects::nonNull);
}

static class StopIterationException extends RuntimeException {}

public void init() {
    if (repository.count() == 0) {
        Level logLevel = INFO;
        try {
            read("providers.csv", fields -> new Provider(
                    fields.readString("code"),
                    fields.readString("name"),
                    LocalDate.parse(fields.readString("effectiveStart"), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE),
                    LocalDate.parse(fields.readString("effectiveEnd"), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            )).forEach(repository::save);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logLevel = WARNING;
            LOG.log(logLevel, "Initialization was interrupted");
        } catch (StopIterationException ignored) {}
        LOG.log(logLevel, "{} providers imported.", repository.count());
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't thinking outside the box. That is using exceptions for flow control. It is generally accepted to be a bad practice for a number of reasons.

Comment: You can argue about good and bad design all you like - it is the only option that actually works. Blanket rules of what is considered good or bad come with caveats that the user should understand the rationale for the assigned status. In this case the reasons are potential code obfuscation, and the cost of exception handling setup. Neither of those reasons are relevant here and they are outweighed by the need for a working solution.  In some languages like Python using exceptions for flow control is normal - it is how iteration terminates in the core language classes.

Comment: Ultimately, not using exceptions for flow control stems from how exceptions came to be - to stop using flow control (ie magic result values) to signal exceptional states. And to allow exception handling to be orthogonal to flow control. These are all great ideas but ideals are always trumped by pragmatism. In this case throwing an exception is the only available mechanism for passing a message to the calling code.

Answer (score -4):

My solution was to generate a null when done and then apply a filter

```
Stream
 .generate( o -> newObject() )
 .filter( o -> o != null )
 .forEach(...)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because the generator doesn't stop in this case.